# onClickで実行している処理を、PCからの命令をトリガーに実行するようにしたい

Tags: android, sh

onClickで実行している処理を、PCからの命令をトリガーに実行するようにしたいです。
スタートボタン押下を、PCから命令したいです。

```
package com.pushbutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void onClickGrtBtn(View v) {
    Log.v("onClickGrtBtn", "hoge");
}
}
```

Comment: pushなどを考えていましたが、USB経由は盲点でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb shell sendevent`
でどうでしょうか？

詳しい使い方はぐぐったら下記ブログがでてきました

http://techblog.qoncept.jp/?p=356